# Missing Android Studio Tools from Android like Activity

Tags: android

I am doing my first tutorial from Android Studio and I dont have tools like a man did https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu41h6EvTPw 6:35

I mean those android tools like activity etc

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjNSZ.png)

Comment: The Android SDK path is not set as far as I know by looking at the provided screenshot.

Comment: i changed from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-all.zip  to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip

Answer (score 0):

Did you wait for Gradle to finish and downloaded all updates for Android Studio? Some basic features are blocked when you open project and are still being processed by Gradle.

Comment: Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Answer (score 0):

After Gradle build finished, if not fix do this:

At the top of files list, left side, click on `Project`

Then click on `Android`